# Why alter curl_multi_timeout() return value?

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

[This](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fopen.html) sample code contains:

```
curl_multi_timeout(multi_handle, &curl_timeo);
if(curl_timeo >= 0) {
  timeout.tv_sec = curl_timeo / 1000;
  if(timeout.tv_sec > 1)
    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
  else
    timeout.tv_usec = (curl_timeo % 1000) * 1000;
}
```

Why is `tv_sec` clipped to 1 second?  Why isn't the value returned by `curl_multi_timeout()` used as-is (after dividing by 1000)?

Assuming there's a good reason for the above, then is there a case when you would NOT clip the value to 1 second?  What case is that?

Answer (score 1):

The code is just setting a maximum wait time for the later call to `select()`.  If anything, this looks like a bug.  It looks as if the code is protecting itself from an unreasonable answer from `curl_multi_timeout()`.  My guess is that the coder was thinking, "if the curl timeout function returns something longer than one minute, then don't wait any longer than that." ...and then proceeded to typo one minute as one second.  It probably should be doing

```
if (timeout.tv_sec > 60) {
    timeout.tv_sec = 60;
else if (timeout.tv_sec == 0) {
    timeout.tv_usec = curl_timeo * 1000;
}
```

The mod by 1000 is unnecessary since `curl_multi_timeout()` returns milliseconds, so if `tv_sec` is zero, that means that the returned value is in the range of 0 - 999.

Comment: But tv_usec is microseconds. If curl_timeo is milliseconds, then you do need to multiply by 1000. It's just the mod that seems wrong.  Right?

Comment: @Paul: No, tv_usec is milliseconds as well -- you don't need the additional factor of 1000.  If you were using microseconds, you be using a `struct timespec` which has a `tv_nsec` member for microseconds.  The code uses the older `struct timeval`.

Comment: No, tv_usec really is microseconds: 'u' is the SI prefix for micro.  Among other places: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Elapsed-Time.html

Comment: that also means the mod is correct: 1001ms = 1s (curl_timeo / 1000) plus 1000ms (curl_timeo % 1000 * 1000).

Comment: @Paul: You're right, it is microseconds (1/1,000,000th of a second).  The curl timeout return is in 1/1,000ths, and then it has to get converted to milliseconds for `tv_usec`... the multiply by 1000 is correct.  I've edited the code above to account for that.